# How to return select query in pl pgsql

Tags: postgresql

While running a Select query returning all columns in Pl Pgsql
written in a function, 
during passing the arguments error is shown.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(ENROLL VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS  SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE CALTYPE VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
SELECT COMPLETED INTO 
CALTYPE FROM TEMPDATA WHERE
ROLL=ENROLL;
    IF CALTYPE='FALSE' THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM SEM8
        WHERE ROLL=ENROLL;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM TEMPDATA
        WHERE ROLL=ENROLL;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('123');
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM myfunc('123');

Comment: getting error while running SELECT * FROM myfunc('123');

Answer (score 1):

Functions returning SETOF RECORD need a column definition.  You can define it at run time like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc('123') mf(columnA TEXT, columnB INTEGER);
```

or you can change the return type of the function to TABLE and define it there like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(ENROLL VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS  TABLE (
    columnA TEXT,
    columnB INTEGER
) AS $$
DECLARE CALTYPE VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
SELECT COMPLETED INTO 
CALTYPE FROM TEMPDATA WHERE
ROLL=ENROLL;
    IF CALTYPE='FALSE' THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM SEM8
        WHERE ROLL=ENROLL;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM TEMPDATA
        WHERE ROLL=ENROLL;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```